# Resolver el juego "Toque y Fama" en pyton 3.7

Tags: python-3.7

Muy buenos días, Quería pedir su ayuda en algo. Soy alumno de primer año y me estoy metiendo en el mundo de python. Estoy creando un juego que se llama "Toque y fama". Consiste en el siguiente resultado :

```
Elige el largo del número: 5
Intento 1: 12345
Toques: 2 - Famas: 1
 Intento 2: 32617
Toques: 2 - Famas: 2
Intento 3: 32781
¡Felicitaciones! Has acertado en 3 intentos
¿Deseas jugar nuevamente? 1. Sí / 0. No: 1
Elige el largo del número: 4
Intento 1: 1234
Toques: 2 - Famas: 0
Intento 2: 1234
Toques: 2 - Famas: 0
Intento 3: 1234
Toques: 2 - Famas: 0
Intento 4: 1234
Toques: 2 - Famas: 0
- Fin del Juego La secuencia era 2167
¿Deseas jugar nuevamente? 1. Sí / 0. No: 0
Jugados: 2 - Ganados: 1 - Perdidos: 1
```

Esto es lo que llevo en mi ejercicio y me tira error en unas variables. No se como seguir avanzando, favor necesito una ayuda.

```
import random

variable1=str(random.randrange(10))
variable2=str(random.randrange(10))
variable3=str(random.randrange(10))
variable4=str(random.randrange(10))

while(variable1==variable2 or variable1==variable3 or variable1 == variable4 or variable2==variable3 or 
variable2== variable4 or variable3 == variable4):
  variable1 = str(random.randrange(10))
  variable2 = str(random.randrange(10))
  variable3 = str(random.randrange(10))
  variable4 = str(random.randrange(10))
  print(variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4)
  n=str(input("Ingrese el numero que deseas encontrar"))
  digito1 = n[0]
  digito2 = n[1]
  digito2 = n[2]
  digito2 = n[3]
  print(digito1,digito2,digito3,digito4)

  if(digito1==variable1):
    print("fama")
  else:
    if(digito1==variable2 or digito1==variable3 or digito1==variable4):
      print("Toque")
      if(digito2==variable2):
        print("fama")
      else:
        if(digito2==variable3 or digito1==variable4):
          print("Toque")
```

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo. por favor, mira [ask]

Comment: No existe `digito3`, `digito4`, haz cambio el valor de `digito2` varias veces, ese es tu error te haz equivocado al poner esas variables y lo has puesto como `digito2`

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias por responder. Le muestro error que tirar (line 9
    variable1 = str(random.randrange(10))
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @christian, muchas gracias por responder. Corregiré la definición de las variables.

Comment: Identa correctamente todo, eso lo puede hacer tu editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según muestra el ejemplo, el juego debe manejar problemas de cualquier largo, mientras que el código que tienes sólo manejas problemas de largo cuatro.

Para representar el número secreto y el valor ingresado por la persona usaremos listas de digitos (en caracteres), como

```
guess = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
numero_secreto = ['8', '5', '3', '4']
```

Primero tenemos una función que cuenta los toques y las famas.

```
def analizar(guess, numero_secreto):
    toques = len(set(guess) & set(numero_secreto))
    famas = sum([1 if guess[i] == numero_secreto[i] else 0 for i in range(len(guess))])
    return toques, famas
```

Para calcular los toques, convertimos ambas listas en conjuntos y hacemos la intersección, lo que nos devuelve un conjunto con los digitos comunes a ambas listas. El largo del conjunto es igual al número de dígitos en común.

Para calcular los toques recorreremos ambas listas comparando los valores en la misma posición. Si son iguales, generamos un `1`, si no, un `0` usando el operador ternario

```
1 if guess[i] == numero_secreto[i] else 0
```

que es una forma compacta de escribir

```
if guess[i] == numero_secreto[i]:
    valor = 1
else:
    valor = 0
```

El `main` parte por pedir el largo del problema, que debe estar entre 1 y 10:

```
def main():
    max_intentos = 3
    largo = 0
    while largo < 1 or largo > 10:
        largo = int(input("Elige el largo del número: "))
```

A continuación entramos en un ciclo infinito. En cada pasada, generamos un número secreto para un nuevo juego.

Para generar el número, desordenamos la lista de digitos usando `shuffle`. Los primeros digitos del resultado será el número secreto.

```
digitos = list("0123456789")
while True:
    random.shuffle(digitos)
    numero_secreto = digitos[:largo]

    # print(numero_secreto)
```

Luego le damos tres intentos:

```
    for intento in range(max_intentos):
        guess = list(input(f"Intento {intento + 1}: ")[:largo])
        toques, famas = analizar(guess, numero_secreto)
        if guess == numero_secreto:
            print(f"¡Felicitaciones! Has acertado en {intento + 1} intentos")
            break
        else:
            print(f"Toques {toques} - Famas {famas}: ")
    else:
        print(f"No acertastes. El número era {''.join(numero_secreto)}.")
```

Finalizado el juego (con éxito o fracaso) le damos la oportunidad de seguir o abandonar. Para simplificar, tomamos la opción del usuario, eliminamos los espacios, reducimos a minúsculas y comparamos lo que queda con "s" o "si".

```
    opcion = input("¿Deseas jugar nuevamente (S/N)? ").lower().strip()
    if opcion not in ["s", "si"]:
        break
```

**Código completo**

```
import random

def analizar(guess, numero_secreto):
    toques = len(set(guess) & set(numero_secreto))
    famas = sum([1 if guess[i] == numero_secreto[i] else 0 for i in range(len(guess))])
    return toques, famas

def main():
    max_intentos = 3
    largo = 0
    while largo < 1 or largo > 10:
        largo = int(input("Elige el largo del número: "))

    digitos = list("0123456789")
    while True:
        random.shuffle(digitos)
        numero_secreto = digitos[:largo]
        # print(numero_secreto
        for intento in range(max_intentos):
            guess = list(input(f"Intento {intento + 1}: ")[:largo])
            toques, famas = analizar(guess, numero_secreto)
            if guess == numero_secreto:
                print(f"¡Felicitaciones! Has acertado en {intento + 1} intentos")
                break
            else:
                print(f"Toques {toques} - Famas {famas}: ")
        else:
            print(f"No acertastes. El número era {''.join(numero_secreto)}.")
        opcion = input("¿Deseas jugar nuevamente (S/N)? ").lower().strip()
        if opcion not in ["s", "si"]:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

produce:

```
Elige el largo del número: 4
Intento 1: 1234
Toques 2 - Famas 0: 
Intento 2: 1256
Toques 1 - Famas 1: 
Intento 3: 3465
Toques 3 - Famas 1: 
No acertastes. El número era 8453.
¿Deseas jugar nuevamente (S/N)?
```

Otro juego más largo:

```
Elige el largo del número: 8
Intento 1: 01234567
Toques 7 - Famas 3: 
Intento 2: 80123456
Toques 7 - Famas 0: 
Intento 3: 09123456
Toques 6 - Famas 0: 
No acertastes. El número era 14206587.
¿Deseas jugar nuevamente (S/N)?
```

Comment: @VerdadesOcultas leiste el [tour] no?? entonces sabes que la forma de agradecer es votando y aceptando las respuestas, no dejando un comentario de gracias....